# Exiting a python application for 'GAME OVER'

Tags: python, visual-studio

I would like to know why this code does not work; it should exit at the "GAME OVER" point, but it continues to my next defined function.
I have tried other variations on exit() such as: `sys.exit()`, `quit()` and `SystemExit`.

```
run_attack = input("What do you do: Run/Attack\n")
run = ['run', 'Run', 'RUN']
attack = ['attack', 'Attack', 'ATTACK']
run_attack = 1
while run_attack < 10:
    if run_attack == ("run") or ("Run") or ("RUN"):
        print ("You turn to run from the wolf but he quickly pounces 
               you...")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("You are quickly ripped apart and just about get to see 
             yourself be eaten.")
        print("GAME OVER")
        break
        exit()       #This is where the game should exit, yet after input it 
                            continues to the next function


    elif run_attack == ("attack") or ("Attack") or ("ATTACK"):
         print("You brace yourself for a bite and have no time to reach" 
                 "for any kind of weapon form your backpack.")
        time.sleep("2")
        input("You clock the dog hard, twice on the muzzle.")
        print("The dog recoils in pain and retreats back to the woods.")
        print("You quickly start running as you assume there will be a den in the woods.")
        break       

    else:
        input("Type Run or Attack...")
```

Comment: One immediate issue in your code is that you're redefining run_attack just after getting user input for it.

Comment: Also another quick tip, instead of comparing against `("attack") or ("Attack") or ("ATTACK")`, call `.lower()` on `run_attack` and compare it agianst `"attack"`.

Comment: And why are you `break`ing if you want the code under it to run? `exit` is never being called.

Comment: So how would i define the answer to input("What do you do: Run/Attack")  as run_attack without writing that? Thank you for the input so quickly.

Comment: without breaking it repeats the loop "You turn to run but he quickly pounces you"

Comment: `a == b or c or d` isn't valid for what you want, it should be `a == b or a == c or a == d`

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your code; why did you write this much without testing it?

First, you read the user's input, immediately replace is with `1`, and then try to test it (incorrectly) as if it were still a string.  Your posted code has several syntax errors, so I have some trouble reproducing the problem.  However, the immediately obvious problem is here:

```
    break
    exit()       # This is where ...
```

You can't get to the `exit` statement, as you `break` from the loop just before you can get there.

---

I strongly recommend that you back up to a few lines and use incremental programming: write a few lines at a time, debug those, and don't continue until they do what you want.

Also look up how to test a variable against various values.  Your `if` statement is incorrect.  Instead, try the list inclusion you're trying to set up:

```
if run_attack in run:
    ...
elif run_attack in attack:
    ...
```

Comment: I think mentioning that he could call `.lower()` on `run_attack` and compare it against the lowered version of its value (`"attack"`) would significantly increase reliability. NOTE. AttaCK won't pass

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, will give it a go. It was doing what i wanted until exit...

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty of rewriting your whole program to show you a few things wrong with it and a few tricks. I've done it without the loop, since you never use it anyway... you can add the `while` loop later once you've mastered it, but you should really go back to basics on some things here:

```
run_attack = input("What do you do: Run/Attack\n")

if run_attack.lower() == "run":
    print("""some
        stuff
        with
        multiple
        lines and GAME OVER""")
    exit()

elif run_attack in ("attack", "Attack", "ATTACK"):
    print("""some
        stuff
        with
        multiple
        lines""")

else:
    input("Type Run or Attack...")
```

Some notes:

1. Using `"""` for strings enables you to write multiple lines without multiple `print` statements
2. Using `str.lower()` on strings makes everything easy to compare because you only have to compare it to the lowercase version of each string. However for `attack` you can notice I used a different inclusion test, without multiple conditions. Either way works here.
3. Like the other answer here (and many comments), you should use only `exit()` to leave the program entirely, or only `break` to exit the loop and continue to other code that's beneath the entire loop.
4. When you rewrite your loop, with a condition like `while number_of_turns < 10` don't forget to add `1` to the number of turns on each loop, otherwise that condition is **always** `True` and you'll have an infinite loop...

I'm actually quite surprised this code had any resemblance to the behavior you expected from it, my suggestion is to go back over to the basics of python, learn loops, string methods, basic commands. The rest is already said in the other answer here (which is better than mine, frankly) just wanted to add some ideas.

Comment: Thanks man, i know you can do it this way too print("Stuff\n"
                                                                                  "stuff")

Comment: Like i say, still getting adjusted to programming

Comment: How come you didn't use ".lower()" for the elif?

Comment: Just to show you another option of doing the same thing, I could have used `lower` for both